# Is it possible to only display SourceContext in Serilog if ForContext<class> has been defined

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am new to Serilog and I am struggling with displaying the class name only when required without having to add `{SourceContext:l}`to each log message. I am aware I can just write the code as:

```
Log.ForContext<Class1>().Verbose("message {SourceContext:l}");
```

I have the logger being setup as below:

```
    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo
                .ColoredConsole(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:G} [{Level}] {SourceContext} {Message}{NewLine:l}{Exception:l}")
                .CreateLogger();
```

I am hoping to only have the class name displayed when the class has been specified as seen here.

```
Log.ForContext<Class1>().Verbose("message");
```

And not displayed if the log is created like.

```
Log.Verbose("message");
```

However on the above example it will print a log out in the format of 
'{SourceContext} message' instead of just 'message' which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug in `ColoredConsoleSink` - generally when rendering output tokens a missing value will be left blank.

Raised: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/649

You might try switching to the Literate Console sink (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-literate) which I don't believe has this bug.